# Service not getting imported in Component

Tags: angularjs-service

I have created a service and placed it in a new folder 'service' under app folder.

When I am trying to import the service in component its showing error as follows:

[image]

But, the same is getting imported in app module.

[image]

Someone please help me out...

Here is my project structure below
[image]

My alert service is in service folder.
And trying to import it in home.component which is in home folder

Comment: You must have the relative path incorrect... Are both files in the same directory?

Comment: Please find the snapshot I added in above ques.
Dont get confuse by seeing ExampleService and AlertService.. I renamed it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Need to mention

import {AlertService} from '../service/alert.service';